# How can I write an edit controller

Tags: node.js, backend

I have a nodeJS backend and a controller to add a specific function. There's an add function but there's no update function. how can I write an update function. I'm not good with backend and I have been tasked with this.

Below is the add function for the feature. How do I write a function like that for update:

```
async addRole(req, res, next) {
let body = req.body;
const model = new entityRoles(body);
try {
    const alreadyExist = await entityRoles.getByName(req.body.name);
    if (!alreadyExist) {
        const saveResponse = await model.save()
        return res.status(httpStatus.OK).json(new APIResponse(saveResponse, 'Entity role created successfully.', httpStatus.OK));

    } else if (alreadyExist.roleName === req.body.roleName) {
        res
            .status(httpStatus.OK)
            .send({ message: "name is already exist" });
    } else {
        res
            .status(httpStatus.OK)
            .send({ message: "Error Adding entity role" });
    }

} catch (e) {
    if (e.code === 11000) {
        return res
            .status(httpStatus.OK)
            .send({ message: "entity role is already exist with this name" });
    } else {
        return res.status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json(new APIResponse({}, 'Error adding entity role', httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e));
    }
}
```

EDIT: the framework used is express.js, ODM is mongoose and the database is mongodb

Comment: Do you use an ORM like sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async updateRole(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const roleId = req.params.id; // Extract the role ID from the request parameters
    const updatedRoleData = req.body; // Extract the updated role information from the reque`enter code here`st body

    const existingRole = await entityRoles.findById(roleId);
    if (!existingRole) {
      return res.status(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND).send({ message: "Role not found." });
    }

    // Update the existing role with the updated role information
    existingRole.name = updatedRoleData.name;
    existingRole.description = updatedRoleData.description;
    // Update other properties as needed

    const updatedRole = await existingRole.save();

    return res.status(httpStatus.OK).json(new APIResponse(updatedRole, 'Role updated successfully.', httpStatus.OK));
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json(new APIResponse({}, 'Error updating role.', httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, error));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear such as: framework, orm library, database. But this below code is sample that you can reference:

```
async function updateRole(req, res, next) {
  /**
   * Structure body
   * @example
   * {
   *   id: 1, // id of role
   *   name: 'admin' // new name of role
   * }
   */
  const body = req.body;

  try {
    const model = await entityRoles.findById(req.body.id);
    /**
     * Check have model exist on database
     */
    if (!model) {
      return res.status(httpStatus.OK).send({ message: 'not found role by id' });
    }
    /**
     * Check new name of role is existed in database
     *
     * `body.name !== model.name` this statement make sure check role is correctly
     * because always exist one role with old name that get from database in previous statement.
     */
    if (body.name !== model.name && (await entityRoles.getByName(body.name))) {
      return res.status(httpStatus.OK).send({ message: 'name is already exist' });
    }
    /**
     * Add more your business logic at here such as check other filed or name is correctly
     */

    /**
     * Finally, model will be updated with new data and save to database.
     */
    model.name = body.name;
    /**
    * Update rest of role
    * @example 
    * model.lastUpdatedAt = Date.now();
    */ 
    const saveResponse = await model.save();
    return res.status(httpStatus.OK).json(new APIResponse(saveResponse, 'Entity role updated successfully.', httpStatus.OK));
  } catch (e) {
    /**
     * Check `code` of error to return client
     */
    if (e.code === 11000) {
      return res.status(httpStatus.OK).send({ message: 'name of role is existed. please update a other name.' });
    } else {
      return res
        .status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        .json(new APIResponse({}, 'Error adding entity role', httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: th framework is expressjs, ODM is mongoose and the database is mongodb

Comment: @Bruno I was updated new code for mongoose query.